# BTC Miner, trust? or scam?

Tags: blockchain, wallet, bitcoin-cash, trust

trust to miner who after the investment ask You other btc to have free access to unspendable-btc in the wallet? any suggestion?

Comment: This is a common scam. Do not send money. You will not get access to the unspendable BTC in your wallet, the scammer will just pocket your money.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I've been asked to share wallet credentials to participate in mining. Is that a scam?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/66934/ive-been-asked-to-share-wallet-credentials-to-participate-in-mining-is-that-a). See also https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=miner+scam and also [Bitcoin Mining as a Newbie (link wallet to another person's miner)](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/74841/13866)